# Bind InfoPath Form Field to SharePoint Mult-select column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I have a SharePoint list checkbox multi-select column that contains a list of products. In InfoPath, when I bind that column to a multiple selection listbox control the values show up as:

_ Enter Choice #1

_ Enter Choice #2

_ Enter Choice #3

How do I get it to show the actual values from the SP list column itself?  I'm expecting to see something like this:

_ Product Name 1

_ Product Name 2

_ Product Name 3

etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you customizing the list form using InfoPath?

You can drag a field from Fields to add it to the form instead of adding a new multiple selection list box control.

1. Under DATA tab, click Show Fields to display fields.

   [image]
2. Drag your field from the Fields and drop it to the form where you want

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

**By default,** the `Multiple Selection list` box sets the entries to be added **manually**, so it shows to you like this

[image]

**To get Product list InfoPath, try to do the following:**

- Create a secondary data with your product list.
- Right click on `Multiple Selection list` > Properties.
- Select "**Get choices from**" `an external data list` to get data from your secondary connection or "`from fields in this form`" to get choices from the current form!

[image]